# Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand how to fix this error.

Warning: prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Its in the if statement below.  Is this happening since the first value doesn't have a previous and I need to deal with that condition?  Weirdly this worked in regular .php but not in the framework I have it in now.

I'm trying to generate an XML file based on a result set returned for a query.  (I'm open to better ideas)

```
    $export.= '<Campaigns>';
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        //echo '<Email Timestamp="' . $line['EmailTimeStamp'] . '" ';
        $export.=  '<Campaign Info="' . $line['EmailTrackingNumber'] . '" EmailId="' .$line['EmailId'] . '">';
        $export.=  '<Emails>';
                if (prev($line['EmailTrackingNumber']) == current($line['EmailTrackingNumber'])) {
                    $export.=  '<Email Timestamp="' . $line['EmailTimeStamp'] . '" ';
                    $export.=  'City="' . $line['City'] . '" ';
                    $export.=  'Zip="' . $line['Zip'] . '"';
                }
        $export.=  '</Emails></Campaign>';
        }
    $export.= '</Campaigns></EmailTrackingData>';
    //echo $export;
    file_put_contents('DateOfFile-export.xml', $export);
```

Comment: It's happening because you're passing a string to `prev()`, and it is expecting an array. In this case, if I understand your code correctly, you're trying to output things based on whether variables in this database row have changed - you just need to save the variables from the previous loop iteration somewhere and compare them with the current variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
prev($line['EmailTrackingNumber'])
```

is not an array but a string. This

```
prev($line)
```

makes more sense. It returns the array entry which is before the current entry of `$line`.

But I think you would like to compare the last record with the current record. But that does not work like this. You can only access the columns of the current record. You have to temporarly save your last record.

```
$export.= '<Campaigns>';

$lastLine = null;

while ($line =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //echo '<Email Timestamp="' . $line['EmailTimeStamp'] . '" ';
    $export.=  '<Campaign Info="' . $line['EmailTrackingNumber'] . '" EmailId="' .$line['EmailId'] . '">';
    $export.=  '<Emails>';

    if ($lastLine['EmailTrackingNumber'] == $line['EmailTrackingNumber']) {
        $export.=  '<Email Timestamp="' . $line['EmailTimeStamp'] . '" ';
        $export.=  'City="' . $line['City'] . '" ';
        $export.=  'Zip="' . $line['Zip'] . '"';
    }

    $export.=  '</Emails></Campaign>';
    $lastLine = $line;
}
$export.= '</Campaigns></EmailTrackingData>';
//echo $export;
file_put_contents('DateOfFile-export.xml', $export);
```